# Error using an importmap: "Error while transforming file. See the terminal for more information."

Tags: javascript

I am experimenting with script type="importmap" and have an issue that I am sure has a simple answer.

This works:

```
<html>
    <head>
       ....
        <script type="module">
            import './webcomponents/lit-test.js';
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <lit-test></lit-test>
    </body>
</html>
```

This doesn't:

```
<html>
    <head>
       ....
        <script type="importmap">
            {
                "imports": {
                    "lit-test": "./webcomponents/lit-test.js"
                }
            }
        </script>
        <script type="module">
            import 'lit-test';
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <lit-test></lit-test>
    </body>
</html>
```

The error in the browser:

> Error while transforming file. See the terminal for more information.

The error in the console:

> GET http://localhost:8000/ 500 (Internal Server Error)

Can anyone explain what is incorrect?

**lit-test.js**

```
import { css, html, LitElement } from 'lit';

class Lit_test extends LitElement {
    render() {
        return html` Hello `;
    }
}
customElements.define('lit-test', Lit_test);
```

The terminal:

[image]

File structure:

[image]

Comment: What are you using to do the transformation? Do you use a bundler or transpiler?

Comment: I am not using anything other than this. I have read something about having to use something like Babel to transpile, but will this only work with this extra step? The aim is to keep it as simple as possible. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script/type/importmap suggests it should work as is.

Comment: It seems then the error exists within the `lit-test` module. Are there any other errors you can provide?

Comment: I have added lit-test.js. Nothing complicated as you can see. Only other error in the terminal added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to install `@web/dev-server-import-maps` plugin if you are using development server.

**Install the package:**

```
npm i --save-dev @web/dev-server-import-maps
```

Add the plugin to your `web-dev-server.config.mjs` or `web-test-runner.config.js`:

```
import { importMapsPlugin } from '@web/dev-server-import-maps';

export default {
  plugins: [importMapsPlugin()],
};
```

**[For More Information](https://modern-web.dev/docs/dev-server/plugins/import-maps/#installation)**

Comment: Genius - that was the problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad I could help you find the solution to the problem.